# Popover with UINavigationController/UITableViewController cropping nav bar

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, popover

I've implemented a Popover that is composed of a UINavigationController that has a UITableViewController embedded. When the popover comes up, the navigation bar is cropped on the top and sides. I've attempted to use solutions I've read here with forcing the size - setting it to CGRectMake(0,0) then to the right size on ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear but it has no effect. The UINavigationController and UITableViewController have Size as Freeform in the Simulated Metrics (although I've tried Inferred, to no avail as well). I've tried setting the popover size to an explicit size, still no go. It ignores all of my attempts to make it look right.

What is the key to making a popover look good with a dynamic TableView?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this problem. I removed embedding of the UITableViewController in a UINavigationController and instead added a UINavigationBar to the header of the UITableView. The view appears correctly now with correct sizing of the navigation bar and buttons.